# I just see project template blazorserver, Why I don't see project template blazor, blazorhosted, blazorlib, blazorserverside?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

cmd

```
C:\Users\donhuvy>dotnet --version
3.0.100-preview8-013656
```

and

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1087]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\donhuvy>dotnet new --help
Usage: new [options]

Options:
  -h, --help          Displays help for this command.
  -l, --list          Lists templates containing the specified name. If no name is specified, lists all templates.
  -n, --name          The name for the output being created. If no name is specified, the name of the current directory is used.
  -o, --output        Location to place the generated output.
  -i, --install       Installs a source or a template pack.
  -u, --uninstall     Uninstalls a source or a template pack.
  --nuget-source      Specifies a NuGet source to use during install.
  --type              Filters templates based on available types. Predefined values are "project", "item" or "other".
  --dry-run           Displays a summary of what would happen if the given command line were run if it would result in a template creation.
  --force             Forces content to be generated even if it would change existing files.
  -lang, --language   Filters templates based on language and specifies the language of the template to create.
  --update-check      Check the currently installed template packs for updates.
  --update-apply      Check the currently installed template packs for update, and install the updates.


Templates                                         Short Name               Language          Tags
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console Application                               console                  [C#], F#, VB      Common/Console
Class library                                     classlib                 [C#], F#, VB      Common/Library
WPF Application                                   wpf                      [C#], VB          Common/WPF
WPF Class library                                 wpflib                   [C#], VB          Common/WPF
WPF Custom Control Library                        wpfcustomcontrollib      [C#], VB          Common/WPF
WPF User Control Library                          wpfusercontrollib        [C#], VB          Common/WPF
Windows Forms (WinForms) Application              winforms                 [C#], VB          Common/WinForms
Windows Forms (WinForms) Class library            winformslib              [C#], VB          Common/WinForms
Worker Service                                    worker                   [C#]              Common/Worker/Web
Unit Test Project                                 mstest                   [C#], F#, VB      Test/MSTest
NUnit 3 Test Project                              nunit                    [C#], F#, VB      Test/NUnit
NUnit 3 Test Item                                 nunit-test               [C#], F#, VB      Test/NUnit
xUnit Test Project                                xunit                    [C#], F#, VB      Test/xUnit
Razor Component                                   razorcomponent           [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
Razor Page                                        page                     [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewImports                                   viewimports              [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewStart                                     viewstart                [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
Blazor Server App                                 blazorserver             [C#]              Web/Blazor
ASP.NET Core Empty                                web                      [C#], F#          Web/Empty
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)      mvc                      [C#], F#          Web/MVC
ASP.NET Core Web App                              webapp                   [C#]              Web/MVC/Razor Pages
ASP.NET Core with Angular                         angular                  [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js                        react                    [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux              reactredux               [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
Razor Class Library                               razorclasslib            [C#]              Web/Razor/Library/Razor Class Library
ASP.NET Core Web API                              webapi                   [C#], F#          Web/WebAPI
ASP.NET Core gRPC Service                         grpc                     [C#]              Web/gRPC
dotnet gitignore file                             gitignore                                  Config
global.json file                                  globaljson                                 Config
NuGet Config                                      nugetconfig                                Config
Dotnet local tool manifest file                   tool-manifest                              Config
Web Config                                        webconfig                                  Config
Solution File                                     sln                                        Solution
Protocol Buffer File                              proto                                      Web/gRPC

Examples:
    dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
    dotnet new react --auth Individual
    dotnet new --help

C:\Users\donhuvy>
```

while I read the book "Blazor Revealed" by Peter Himschoot ( https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484243428 )

[image]

I just see project template blazorserver, Why I don't see project template blazor, blazorhosted, blazorlib, blazorserverside?

Even, When I use Visual Studio

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview
Version 16.3.0 Preview 2.0
VisualStudio.16.Preview/16.3.0-pre.2.0+29209.152
```

[image]
Seemly missing some type of blazor project template. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ran the following command: `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates`?

It is required if you want to use Blazor templates from command line.

Further info can be found here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7642#issuecomment-464365166

Answer (score 3):

The client-side Blazor templates are not yet built-in to ASP.NET Core as client-side Blazor isn’t fully finished yet. That’s why you only get the “Blazor Server App” template in your list.

To start with client-side Blazor development, you first need to install the templates. You can do so by running the following command, as explained in the [“Getting Started” documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio):

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview8.19405.7
```

Once you have done that, the templates should be available and you can create a client-side Blazor application using `dotnet new blazorwasm`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have executed

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview8.19405.7
```

see [this page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-8/) for all steps.

And then, in VS, just pick that Blazor App and click Next.

After that, there are choices for a Server App and a WebAssembly (Client) App.

The client-side version has a checkbox for [X] Hosted

The server-side version has options for Authentication.

On my PC I seem to have some old templates (leftovers from preview7 and before ?). So check you have the right version before clicking Create.